# Cryptography in PHP and windows phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, encryption

I am working on a project in Windows phone 8 with PHP website backend, I have encrypt a secrit code in PHP using this code

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['op'])) {
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  enter text
<input name="data" type="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="op" name="op" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
}else {
$buffer = $_POST['data']; 
// get the amount of bytes to pad
$extra = 8 - (strlen($buffer) % 8);
// add the zero padding
if($extra > 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $extra; $i++) {
        $buffer .= "\0";
    }
}
// very simple ASCII key and IV
$key = "passwordDR0wSS@P6660juht";
$iv = "password";
// hex encode the return value
echo "Result: ".bin2hex(mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $buffer, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv));   
}
?>
```

This code is working properly. Now I want to decrypt this secret code in Windows phone application, I found a code for windows form application but this code is not working in Windows phone application, it display dll errors the c# code is

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace TestBed {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("passwordDR0wSS@P6660juht");
            byte[] iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("password");
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test");
            byte[] enc = new byte[0];
            TripleDES tdes = TripleDES.Create();
            tdes.IV = iv;
            tdes.Key = key;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            ICryptoTransform ict = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
            enc = ict.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(Bin2Hex(enc));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        // my bin2hex implementation        
        static string Bin2Hex(byte[] bin) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bin.Length * 2);
            foreach(byte b in bin) {
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x").PadLeft(2, '0'));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Any one help me please to decrypt the secret code in Windows phone 8 application

Comment: *what* errors does it display (sheesh)

Comment: You seen to be encrypting data on both ends and not deceypting it anywhere? This doesn't really make sense...